# Is the following sequence performant: dataframes cartesian product -> groupby -> reduce

Tags: pandas, group-by, cartesian-product

I'm interested in performing a groupby-reduce operation on the cartesian product between two dataframes (say `df1` and `df2`).

With my current implementation, these dataframes are fairly big (GBs) and I have split them into smaller chunks for the cartesian product to fit into RAM.
The full-scale application actually rely on dask and takes days to complete which is not sufficient.

I am under the impression that my current implementation is not performant and that speed and memory footprint could be improved if I was able to simulateneously perform the cartesian product and groupby/reduce operation.
Here is a sketch of how the computation looks like at the moment:

```
for df1_chunk, df2_chunk in zip(df1_chunks, df2_chunks):
    df_product = cartesian_product(df1, df2) # dataframes holding the cartesian product
    results.append(df_product.groupby.reduce)
```

where df1_chunks and df2_chunks are lists of df1 and df2 chunks.

What I am wondering is whether the following could be more performant:

```
for r1 in df1_rows:
    for r2 in df2_rows:
        label = get_label(r1, r2)
        results[label] += reduction_increment(r1, r2)
```

with the latter code being written in an optimized form (cython, ...)

does anybody has thoughts about this?

Comment: as mentioned in the post, I'm already distributing this with dask but trying to optimize here the core calculation (i.e. that performed by each dask worker).
I'm also maxing out available computing ressources.

Comment: Sorry, my brain didnt read that part, just saw the pandas tag lol

Comment: no worries, thanks for looking at the post !